# Select custom components to uninstall on Inno Setup uninstaller

Tags: delphi, components, inno-setup, uninstallation

I made installer with Inno Setup. It consist of multiple executables all located in Program Files "APP" folder. But for every executable there's different subfolder in this "APP" folder.

Because every executable is different from purpose, I want to create uninstaller where I can choose, which component I want to uninstall (for example Change button in Add/Remove programs). At the moment uninstaller removes all the applications.

One option is to create different installer for every component and then create installer that contains other installers, but this is too weird.

Is it possible to create custom uninstaller with option to select which component I want to uninstall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What seems that you need is a modify/repair setup option to your application's setup, right?
Take a look in this extension named [UninsHs](http://www.han-soft.com/uninshs.php)

Note: Searching in Google I've found another newer version in other site, but I am not sure if it is legit.

Comment: Found this UninsHs too. But I want to know if this is possible with Inno Setup + Pascal scripting.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do in the Inno uninstaller but it won't "fit in" with the wizard style, and will require showing your own forms, and cancelling the uninstall when you've removed the bits you want.

An alternative is to use the setup (which is slightly better suited for this) and handle components being ticked and unticked.

Both of these will require fairly extensive [Code] being written though.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "An alternative is to use the setup..."? If you've got custom '''install''' wizard pages (ie. a listing of all components to install) how can the setup section be leveraged during an uninstall? Thanks

Comment: You should be able to use the setup to add/remove individual components. While Inno will only automatically install newly selected components and update/repair previously selected components, you will need to handle any uninstallation of components yourself by detecting the component states and removing the appropriate files/registry values.